# Crazyflie: Connecting, logging and parameters-->Add logging config

Tags: ros2, quadcopter, uav, drone, ros2-launch

I would like to define `stateEstimate.vx`, `stateEstimate.vy`, and `stateEstimate.vz` variables to access those data. I used the following code parts.

```
def _connected(self, link_uri):

        self.get_logger().info('Connected!')
        self._lg_stab = LogConfig(name='Stabilizer', period_in_ms=100)
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.x', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.y', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.z', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.vx', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.vy', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.vz', 'float')        
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.roll', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.pitch', 'float')
        self._lg_stab.add_variable('stateEstimate.yaw', 'float')
               
        self._lg_range = LogConfig(name='Range', period_in_ms=100)
        self._lg_range.add_variable('range.zrange', 'uint16_t')
        self._lg_range.add_variable('range.front', 'uint16_t')
        self._lg_range.add_variable('range.right', 'uint16_t')
        self._lg_range.add_variable('range.left', 'uint16_t')
        self._lg_range.add_variable('range.back', 'uint16_t')
        try:
            self._cf.log.add_config(self._lg_stab)
            self._lg_stab.data_received_cb.add_callback(self._stab_log_data)
            self._lg_stab.error_cb.add_callback(self._stab_log_error)
            self._lg_stab.start()
            self._cf.log.add_config(self._lg_range)
            self._lg_range.data_received_cb.add_callback(self._range_log_data)
            self._lg_range.error_cb.add_callback(self._range_log_error)
            self._lg_range.start()

        except KeyError as e:
            print('Could not start log configuration,'
                  '{} not found in TOC'.format(str(e)))
        except AttributeError:
            print('Could not add Stabilizer log config, bad configuration.')
```

When I run my python file via ROS2, I saw the following part on the terminal (`Could not add Stabilizer log config, bad configuration`). I could not get why it happens. However, whenver I use the above code part without `stateEstimate.vx`, `stateEstimate.vy`, and `stateEstimate.vz`, it works pretty well. Could you help us to fix it, thanks.

```
ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/2023-crazy-flie-1/crazyflie_ros2_experimental_2/crazyflie_ros2$ ros2 run crazyflie_ros2 crazyflie_publisher 
[INFO] [1698871075.735318053] [crazyflie_publisher]: Connected!
Could not add Stabilizer log config, bad configuration.
```

Comment: hmm.... strange I didn't get a notification of this support question... I'm even monitoring the UAV tag!. If it takes too long, make an issue on the experimental repository or start a thread on the bitcraze forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself comes from your own  (or the copied) script

```
        except AttributeError:
            print('Could not add Stabilizer log config, bad configuration.')`
```

This is an error but it is not clear why it fails. Here is the API documentation of the crazyflie python library logging functionality:

https://www.bitcraze.io/documentation/repository/crazyflie-lib-python/master/user-guides/python_api/#logging

Here it says that you can only create logblocks for messages that are no larger than 30 bytes. the logblock 'Stabilizer' contains 36 bytes (9 x float which is 4 bytes each). So therefore it fails.

If you look in the documentation, you can see that there is a possibility of declaring a 16 - bit (2 byte) float. In the logblock declaration, you can replace `'float'` with `'FP16'`, and reduce the total message size. This should fix it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the data type and it worked.

Comment: great! good to hear